# how to change state of a react component from another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I saw dozens of examples but they are not working in my case, I want to update the page variable in "bookitem" component and rerender it. using  gives an error ' Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions'

```
    import React from 'react'
import { Pagination, Container } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import bookitem  from './Book_item'

const PaginationI = () => (
    <Container style={{textAlign: "center", padding:'4rem'}}>
  <Pagination defaultActivePage={5} totalPages={10} onPageChange={PageChange}/>
  </Container>
)

function PageChange(event,data){
    console.log(data.activePage);
    <bookitem page={data.activePage}/>
};
export default PaginationI
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
 class bookitem extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super (props);

        this.state={
            counter:0,
            page:0,
            data2:[]

        };
    }

    componentWillMount(){
        console.log(this.props.page)
            axios.get('/books/'+this.state.page).then(res=>{console.log(res.data);this.setState({data2:res.data});})
            console.log('aa')
            console.log(this.state.data2)


    }

    genurl(isbn){
        console.log(isbn)
    let url='http://covers.openlibrary.org/b/isbn/'+ isbn + '-L.jpg'
        return url;
    }

    render(){return(
        <div>
        <div>{this.state.page}</div>
        <Container>
        <div style={{padding:"1em 1em", textAlign: "right"}}>

        <Card.Group itemsPerRow={3} stackable={true} doubling={true}>

        {this.state.data2.map(card=>(
        <Card href="#">
    <Image src={this.genurl(card.isbn)} wrapped ui={false} />
    <Card.Content>
      <Card.Header>{card.title}</Card.Header>
      <Card.Meta>
        <span className='date'>Author:{card.author}</span>
      </Card.Meta>
      <Card.Content >
      <Rating icon='star' defaultRating={card.avgrating} maxRating={5} />
    </Card.Content>
      <Card.Description>
        {card.avgrating} Avg rating, {card.totalratings} total ratings.
      </Card.Description>
    </Card.Content>
    <Card.Content >
      <a>
        <Icon name='pencil alternate' />
        {card.reviews} Reviews
      </a>
    </Card.Content>
  </Card>
  ))}
  
  </Card.Group>
  
        </div>

        </Container>
        </div>
    )
}
}

export default bookitem
```

Comment: For that purpouse you should see [React Redux](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react), as it will help you so much not to make too complex code.

Comment: Couldn't agree less on the fact that redux creates a slimmer code base.. there are several things wrong in this code here. The PageChange function does not return a value for example

Comment: as well as the property `onPageChange` from `Pagination` suggest a function that accepts an event and maybe some data, but does something with it. In this case it should set a state in the current component which is then put as a property on the `bookitem` component. Please also note that Custom React Components in JSX should always follow the `PascalCase` in this case `bookitem` will not render, it should be refactored to `BookItem`

Comment: I also want to highly recommend that you set up an editor with linter. For example use Visual Studio Code with Eslint plugin to lint and format your code. It will really help you tremendously. If you start with something like `npx create-react-app my-app` and open the resulting repo in vs code, all of the aforementioned will work out of the box. Lift and shift your existing code to this new code base and keep working :)

Comment: I made the changes Rostyslav suggested and I had to use <div>{this.props.page}</div> instead of <div>{this.state.page}</div> and it's now updating the element but 'this.state.page' remains the same so it doesn't fetch the new books, so I just put the pagination code inside bookitem now its working fine. it would have been great to keep them separate. thank you all for your answers and suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are not rendering the `bookitem` component at all. You have to manage the state of your `activePage`, pass it to the `bookitem` and actually render this component.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Pagination, Container } from "semantic-ui-react";
import BookItem from "./Book_item";

const PaginationI = () => {
  const [activePage, setActivePage] = useState(0); // manage the state of activePage

  function PageChange(event, data) {
    setActivePage(data.activePage); // update the state in event handler
  }

  return (
    <Container style={{ textAlign: "center", padding: "4rem" }}>
      <BookItem page={activePage} /> {/* render your component */}
      <Pagination
        defaultActivePage={5}
        totalPages={10}
        onPageChange={PageChange} /> {/* pass event handler */}
    </Container>
  );
};

export default PaginationI;
```

Also you would have to rename the `bookitem` component due to collision with HTML tags like this

```
import React from "react";

class BookItem extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      counter: 0,
      page: 0,
      data2: [],
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    console.log(this.props.page);
    axios.get("/books/" + this.state.page).then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data);
      this.setState({ data2: res.data });
    });
    console.log("aa");
    console.log(this.state.data2);
  }

  genurl(isbn) {
    console.log(isbn);
    let url = "http://covers.openlibrary.org/b/isbn/" + isbn + "-L.jpg";
    return url;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{this.state.page}</div>
        <Container>
          <div style={{ padding: "1em 1em", textAlign: "right" }}>
            <Card.Group itemsPerRow={3} stackable={true} doubling={true}>
              {this.state.data2.map((card) => (
                <Card href="#">
                  <Image src={this.genurl(card.isbn)} wrapped ui={false} />
                  <Card.Content>
                    <Card.Header>{card.title}</Card.Header>
                    <Card.Meta>
                      <span className="date">Author:{card.author}</span>
                    </Card.Meta>
                    <Card.Content>
                      <Rating
                        icon="star"
                        defaultRating={card.avgrating}
                        maxRating={5}
                      />
                    </Card.Content>
                    <Card.Description>
                      {card.avgrating} Avg rating, {card.totalratings} total
                      ratings.
                    </Card.Description>
                  </Card.Content>
                  <Card.Content>
                    <a>
                      <Icon name="pencil alternate" />
                      {card.reviews} Reviews
                    </a>
                  </Card.Content>
                </Card>
              ))}
            </Card.Group>
          </div>
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default BookItem;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all Bookitem must starts with capitalized letter. So instead of `<bookitem />` you must have `<Bookitem/>.`

Now if you want to change state of a react component from another component, you have to pass a function from parent to child which will be called when you want to change the state. For example

```
const Compoent1 = () => { 
  const [state, setState] = useState(value)
  .....
  return <Component2 changeState={setState} />
}
```